# Can you store UserId inside Owin OAUTH 2 token?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I need to get UserId from Asp.Net user authorization system because most of my data is stored within SQL and using UserId as a marker which user owns this data. Using Owin OAuth 2.0 I can't get UserId using Identity, it returns `null`. So I've come up with this solution:

*Token provider*

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("user_id", user.Id));
```

*API*

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
var userName = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "user_id").Single().Value;
```

*Simpler API code*

```
var userName = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "user_id").Value;
```

Is this approach good for enterprise business-level application, is it safe, secure and robust? Or will you (maybe) advice something else?

I just don't like the idea of passing UserId inside the token when this functionality is (probably) provided by Microsoft.AspNet.Identity (.NET itself), but as I couldn't make it work, this is my only option for now.

Anyway, I am partly using code from [this great tutorial repository](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/OrdersController.cs). As you can see, this controller has commented lines which are using Identity to get UserId. But this doesn't work for me, so I am using another commented line which uses claims.

Comment: where did you put this two lines of code, in controller or filter?

Comment: In controller (ApiController)

Comment: Every controller will have `User` property so change your first line of code: `ClaimsPrincipal principal = User as ClaimPrincipal;` then it works

Answer (score 4):

Since, you're using OWIN, I'm going to assume you're using ASP.NET Identity, as well. You don't need to store the user id as a claim. You can get it anytime you need via:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

If Intellisense freaks out, you just need to add the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace.

Comment: Well, I **tried** that many times. That includes multiple reinstallation of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core packages, using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity as well, the thing is that `User.Identity.GetUserId()` returns `null`. And yes, my controller is fully protected with [Authorize].

I also tried to install Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin package just now, same result.

Comment: If it returns null, that means the user is anonymous, i.e. not authenticated. Plain and simple. Trying to get the id from a claim wouldn't help, as it will be null there as well.

Comment: Also if it is `null` it may be that you have configured the authentication properly in the `startup.cs`

Comment: Just remembered the OAuth correlation, so let me rephrase a bit. When you authenticate with a third-party via OAuth, that does *not* authenticate you in ASP.NET Identity. There must still be an ASP.NET Identity user, tied to that OAuth login. If you don't take that step of actually creating/signing in the ASP.NET Identity user, then you're still anonymous, no matter how many third-parties you authenticate with. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: I am using Postman to send raw HTTP post and get requests. I successfully get the token and then use it to "get data" from my controller, which is protected. If no (or wrong) token provided, controller sends back an error. If token is correct - everything works. Claims (like in my example) are working just fine and showing everything I need. Identity, however, does not.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, but Identity works just fine. It's been out for over a year, it's at version 2, it's being used by developers all over, including myself, without issue. If `GetUserId` returns null, *you are not authenticated*. Period. Full stop. As to *why* you may not be authenticated, that's an entirely different question.

Comment: Well, by using "pure claims" approach you can use pure Owin without AspNet.Identity dependency, and if you need user-specific information, pass it into the Token. The question is really more of "is this good to store UserId inside the token"

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming **identity** object in the below code is of type **ClaimsIdentity**. How and where are you initializing this object ?

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("user_id", user.Id));
```

If you look at the default template that is generated for a web app in Visual Studio there will be a IdentityModel class where you can see code like below and this is called when you signin in ASP.Net Identity.

```
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
```

Also this is responsible for adding the default claims data and you can also extend this to add additional information like user phonenumber (primarily to avoid a round trip to database and store additional user information as claim).

So when are you creating the **identity** object ?

If you are question is if it is OK to add more information as claim I guess that should be OK. Also what is the output of

```
identity.GetUserId();
```

in your case?

You can further write your own IdentityExtensions class as explained in http://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-identity-20---logging-in-with-email-or-username/

Update 1 -

When you sign in using ASP.Net Identity system it calls GenerateUserIdentityAsync which internally calls CreateAsync method defined in UserClaimsPrincipalFactory class . Here is the code https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/daa50df87feb9f1b59858a22f00a2984996738c6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs . If you look at this method it actually does what you are doing explicitly

```
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme, Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType, Options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType); 
id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, userId)); .
```

So I believe that's what you also need to do

Comment: Output of GetUserId() is `null`. I sort of figured out how to simplify my code: `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "userId").Value;` works as well. And I'm not creating identity object anywhere nor it is declared anywhere, I even do not have database connection in my API controller. API and Token server are completely decoupled, where Token server (with database connection and AccountController) is giving tokens and claims, and API server is simply providing Token-based authorization (resource access)

Comment: So what is the type of identity object in your code identity.AddClaim?

Comment: ClaimsIdentity(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context.Options.AuthenticationType)

Comment: OK. So what I am asking is what is this initialized with ? In case of identity we have something like this `var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`

Comment: `var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);`

where `context` is parameter in `public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)` in my OAuth provider.

Comment: So that's the issue. When you sign in using ASP.Net Identity system it calls `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` which internally calls `CreateAsync` method defined in `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` class . Here is the code https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/daa50df87feb9f1b59858a22f00a2984996738c6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs . If you look at this method it actually does what you are doing explicitly.

Comment: `var id = new ClaimsIdentity(Options.Cookies.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme,
                Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType,
                Options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType);
            id.AddClaim(new Claim(Options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType, userId));` . So I believe that's what you also need to do.

Comment: @RaviA. Your link to the source is an answer in and of itself and completely answers the question of "Can you store UserId inside OWIN OAuth 2 token?" with "Identity does, so yes".  I encourage you to post it as a separate answer, as I was looking for this information and was just fortunate enough to expand the comments section and see your good advice :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, updated my answer with a update..:)